# Going into subfolders (python)

Tags: python

I've written something to remove special characters in Filenames. But it just includes the one folder and not it's subfolders. How can I do this also in subfolders and subsubfolders and so on?

```
import os
import re

def dir_list2(directory, *args):

    fileList = []
    content = os.listdir(directory)

    for file in content :

        dirfile = os.path.join(directory, file)
        if os.path.isfile(dirfile):
            if len(args) == 0:
                fileList.append(dirfile)
            else:
                if os.path.splitext(dirfile)[1][1:] in args:
                    fileList.append(dirfile)

        print "##################################################"

        print "Old filename:", file

        filename = file
        remove = re.compile("[^.a-zA-z0-9_]")
        output = remove.sub('_', filename)

        newfile = directory + "/" + output
        os.rename(dirfile, newfile)

        print "Corrected filename:", output
        #Removes Special Characters


    return fileList

if __name__ == '__main__':


    fileList = dir_list2('/path/')
```

Comment: You might want to use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) instead of `os.listdir`

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) instead of `os.listdir`, it allows you to walk through a folder and its files and subfolders and so on.

Edit your code to be like:

```
content = os.walk(directory)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in content:
    for file in filenames:
        dirfile = os.path.join(dirpath, file)

        # The rest of your code
```

Comment: and how can I exactly do this?

Comment: Thanks for posting my comment as an answer. -1 for not adding anything (e.g. code samples, differences between listdir and walk, etc.)

Comment: Sorry @J0HN I actually was writing my answer didn't see your comment, I will delete my answer if you want :)

Comment: Ok, much better now. +1

Comment: But now it corrects just one filename and if I run the script again it corrects another. And another problem is, that it moves the files from subfolder to the other folder